# Property access and creating in javascript

Tags: javascript

As we can create a object with some properties as follows:

```
let obj = {}; 
obj.pp1 = "abc";
obj.pp2 = 1;
```

**Now the object will have properties pp1 and pp2.**

Now  I am using the same pattern inside a `reduce()` function to summarize the basket contents as follows:

**Approach 1:**

```
const fruitBasket = ['banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'apple', 'cherry', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'fig' ];

const aggregatedBasket = fruitBasket.reduce(
  (ag , item) => {
    if (ag.hasOwnProperty(item) == false){
        ag.item. = 1;
    } else {
        ag.item += 1;
    }
    return ag;
  }, {});

  console.log(aggregatedBasket);
```

But when I run the code, it is returning output as:

> { item: 1 }

I know it is wrong as output is not correct, now I tried the following pattern

**Approach 2:**

```
const aggregatedBasket = fruitBasket.reduce(
  (ag , item) => {
    if (ag.hasOwnProperty(item) == false){
        ag[item] = 1;
    } else {
        ag[item] += 1;
    }
    return ag;
  }, {});
  console.log(aggregatedBasket);
```

Now it is printing the correct output, But I am unable to understand why `.` operator is failing in *Approach 1*.

***Note: I am a beginner in JavaScript, please help me to understand. It might look simple to many experts there.***

Comment: Well `.` and `[ ]` are different. With `.`, the identifier on the right is taken to be the property name. With `[ ]`, the *expression* inside the brackets is evaluated, and its *result* is the property name.

Comment: @Pointy , please explain me with an example. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Your own question is a great example!

Comment: **With [ ], the expression inside the brackets is evaluated, and its result is the property name** - Unable to follow this line, please help me.

Comment: Try changing your working example: `ag[item + " - test"] += 1`.  The code inside the `[ ]` is *evaluated* — the *result* is the property name. With `ag.item`, the property name is always just "item", and it does not matter if "item" happens to be a variable. It is *not* evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

@Pointy's comment as answer

`ag.item` means `ag['item']`, not `ag[item]`. (unless `item='item'` :)

Comment: `item` is already string, no need of `' '`, I think

Comment: @Anil then you get it wrong

Comment: Please correct me, and thanks for pointing my mistake.

Comment: @Anil `item` is identifier, not a string literal, you can see as `let item=1; console.log(item);`

Comment: okay, but our input array contains strings, so with that context, it will string , right?

Comment: @Anil since `ag.item` means `ag['item']`, the value of item variable is not used.